# Setting up SSL for localhost and LAN connections

Tags: apache, security, ssl, phpmyadmin, lamp

I have set up a LAMP server with phpmyadmin. I have apache2 configured (through the Headers mod) to only allow SSL connections, but this is keeping me from accessing phpmyadmin on the LAN. When I setup a subdomain and LetsEncrypt cert I have no problem accessing phpmyadmin (phpmyadmin.example.com), but if I try to access it from the LAN or on the server itself, I can't do so securely, so I can't log in.

Well, on the actual server I can just jam https://localhost/phpmyadmin into the browser and accept the insecure connection warning, but that doesn't work when using a different computer on the LAN (https://server-name/phpmyadmin). I'm not crazy about having phpmyadmin accessible to the outside, even with password protection.

Is there a way to establish a secure connection on a LAN, or do I need some way to exempt the /phpmyadmin folder from the SSL requirement? Can this be done for LAN connections only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to access the URL using the same hostname which was provided as `CN` or `SAN` during certificate generation.

Since you want to access the application locally using `localhost` and any CA will not sign your certificate which has `CN` value `localhost`, you need to live with slef sign certificate generated against `localhost` and import to your keystore.

Command to generate self-signed certificate against localhost:

> openssl req -x509 -out localhost.crt -keyout localhost.key \
>     -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -sha256 \
>     -subj '/CN=localhost' -extensions EXT -config <( \
>      printf "[dn]\nCN=localhost\n[req]\ndistinguished_name = dn\n[EXT]\nsubjectAltName=DNS:localhost\nkeyUsage=digitalSignature\nextendedKeyUsage=serverAuth")

[Here](https://letsencrypt.org/docs/certificates-for-localhost/) is an article on the same.